# How to have border-radius only on last box?

Tags: html, css

I have a "container" which has `border-radius` of `5px` for the bottom left and right corners.  Within the container are stacked boxes or `div`'s. All of the `div`'s are the same size, and they fill up the entire container.

However, the very last `div` looks to be conflicting with the `border-radius` of the last `div`. How can I change it so that the border radius of the bottom `div` matches that of the container?

Note: I can't just go in to the HTML and create a different class or id for that last `div` because they're dynamically generated and they all have the same attributes.

Comment: :last-child {} ,  overflow:hidden on parent, have you tried any of those 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:last-child` selector, and target `bottom border radius`

```
.container div:last-child{
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `:last-child` selector in CSS. You can specify the `border-radius` for the last div in the container.